Is it possible to build a google home application that uses custom sounds?
I was wondering if it is possible to code a Google Home app, specifically an alarm that wakes me up to whatever song that I choose and with its own "hey google" command. To put this in perspective, my sister and I are both deep sleepers and due to this we sometimes have to rush to get to places, but
I've been doing research around but can't find a good starting point starting from where I should code this and what language I should code this in? (it's also been a while since I've been coding, as I've just finished my first year in college and was mainly focusing on the big jump haha).

Google Home and Nest have an alarm clock built in. From the documentation:

Set an alarm on your Google Nest or Home speaker or display to help you wake up or start an important task at the desired time.
You can use your voice or the Nest display screen to set an alarm. The alarm will play only on the speaker or display that you used to set it up.

How to use your Google Home speaker to wake up to music gives these examples:

For a specific band or musician, say, “Hey Google, set an alarm for [time and day] that plays [name of band or musician].”

For a specific song or playlist, say “Hey Google, set a media alarm for [time and day].” Your assistant will ask what you want it to play, and you can respond with the song and artist or playlist title.

For a radio alarm, say, “Hey Google, set a [name of station] radio alarm for [time and day].”

For a specific genre, say, “Hey Google, set a [genre] music alarm for [time and day].”


